# Kernel support for HFS+ or APFS

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, macos, hfs+, apfs

What is the current status for the Linux kernel's support for APFS or HFS+ (filesystems used by MacOS)? Does it support write, journaling etc?

I saw [Is an Apple File System (APFS) driver for linux available or in progress?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481949/is-an-apple-file-system-apfs-driver-for-linux-available-or-in-progress) but the responses there mostly deals with FUSE-solutions. I am, for performance reasons¹, interested in kernel based solutions.

¹ I am gonna run it on an embedded device with a slow CPU, low memory etc.

Comment: Personally, that seems a lower priority than a Linux driver that can operate with Apple's SSD devices (the "soldered-in" variety). No reasonable possibilities for installing Linux on a modern MacBook until this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted an external SSD as APFS, copied files from a MacBook onto it, and Dolphin in Kubuntu 21.10 mounts and opens the SSD no problems. The folders are locked and you need to be root to access them. There's a Dolphin context menu add-on called "Open as Root". (Configure Dolphin > Context Menu > Download New Services). Right-click a folder and Open as Root and you have full access to the external APFS hard drive.

Comment: the question is about **kernel** driver, are you sure that you're not using FUSE driver? There's no kernel driver for APFS yet