# When using apfs-fuse on ubuntu to recover data from a Mac SSD, my Mac user directory doesn't load. Could this be a permissions issue?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I started using apfs-fuse similar to instructions found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481949/is-an-apple-file-system-apfs-driver-for-linux-available-or-in-progress). I am running into a peculiar issue where I can mount the drive successfully and navigate around the drive (information on linux distro and Mac drive below), but my Mac user directory does not load so I am not able to access my Mac files. Could this be a permissions issue? I've also tried different options on apfs-fuse (like using root and user-in-question UID, and also using -l option) but no dice. Any help would be great, thanks!

**information on linux distro and Mac drive**:
I am trying to recover data from a Mac SSD from a MacBook Air running Mojave. This is a sort of lab I have running so that I can get some training on data recovery. I am running a live version of Ubuntu 20.04 from a usb drive on my 2015 MacBook Air (13 inch) and thus install apfs-fuse on the fly after boot up.

So, I can mount the disk successfully using apfs-fuse, but the user directory does not load. Could this be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working on Ubuntu 20.

In order to see/access the files on the apfs mounted drive I had to start nautilus file manager in elevated mode:

$ sudo nautilus

That's all

Comment: Running Nautilus as root is a bad idea; most GUI programs are not intended to be run as root. Also Does that really answer the question?